Getting this error while building my android app(kotlin) NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilationContext

Error -
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilationContext.(org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.storage.FileToPathConverter, org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.storage.FileToPathConverter, boolean, org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.CompilationTransaction, org.jetbrains.kotlin.build.report.ICReporter, boolean, boolean, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)'

build.gradle files
composeOptions {
  kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.11"
}

kotlin {
  jvmToolchain {
      languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(1_8))
   }
}

kotlinOptions {
   jvmTarget = "18"
}


kotlin version-1.9.23
I faced this error while setting up Room,first I had to migrate from kapt to ksp and after that I started facing this error and I tried the 'jvmToolChain'

Does this also occur when you do a clean rebuild?

I also got the same error when I created a new project and was using the latest version of ksp.
I found out that the version I used was not compatible with the Kotlin version.
This versions set fixed for me:
[libraries]
googleKsp = "1.9.23-1.0.20"
kotlin = "1.9.23"
agp = "8.5.0-alpha08"

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
google-devtools-ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "googleKsp"}

